# Keep indexes intact while doing two separate things with series

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a boolean series in which I treat data two different ways. I'm trying to find the local minimum to start a boolean calculation, and anything before that, I'd like to return as `False`. My problem is the only way I can think of to do that is to essentially split the resulting series into two, one from start of group to the row before the minimum, and one from the minimum to the end of the group, finally concatenating them. You can see below that I create a list of False entries, then concatenate that with the boolean series I created starting at the minimum. This is really kludge-y, and it doesn't keep the indexes intact.

```
ser = pd.concat([pd.Series([False] * (argrelextrema(group['B'].values, np.less)[0][:1][0])), (group[argrelextrema(group['B'].values, np.less)[0][:1][0]:].B.diff().shift(-1) <= -1)])
```

From this:

```
       B
5876   500.2
5877   500.3
5878   500.4
5879   498.3
5880   499.0
5881   512  
...
```

I end up with something like this for example:

```
1      False
2      False
3      False
5879   True
5880   False
5881   False
...
```

To fix it, I figured I could reset the indexes starting with the first one of the group, but that seems even more kludge-y.

```
ser.index = np.arange(group.index[0], len(ser))
```

Is there a more elegant way to return `False` for everything before the minimum and combine that with the boolean series I create, keeping all indexes intact?

Comment: Could you give feedback on whether your issue was solved?

Comment: The answer below didn't help. I just decided to stick with the kludge-y way of doing it for now. It's not pretty, but it works. I'm sure there's a better way though.

Comment: How do you calculate your boolean series?

Comment: I think I have the answer. I explained step by step but it can be done in one line. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the operator `&` to create one Boolean series instead of joining two series. In other words, your Boolean series should satisfy **two conditions:**

*Index of item is greater than or equal to index of minimum value*

**AND**

*Item satisfies your other Boolean calculation (which you will then be able to calculate for all items regardless of position)*

```
B = pd.Series([10,9,7,7,12,14])
# Getting first position of minimum value
minValueIndex = B[B == B.min()].index[0]
# Boolean list for condition 1
isAfterMin = B.index >= minValueIndex 
# Boolean list for condition 2: whatever calculation you make, for entire series. Example:
myBoolean = [True, False, True,  True,  False,  True]
# Final Boolean list
ser = isAfterMin & myBoolean

print (ser)
# [False False  True  True False  True]
```

As you can see, items located before the minimum value are always assigned a False, and the other items are assigned the booleans you calculate.

Comment: This definitely seems better, and easily keeps the indexes intact without having to rebuild them.